# Multiple popup windows using javascript

Tags: .net, javascript

i am developing a chat application i need a javascript function to open seperate window for each online users now i am using following javascript code

```
var myWindow;

function openWindow(url)  
{
var width = 700;
var height = 500;
var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth/2) - (width/2));
var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight/2) - (height/2));
var windowFeatures = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",status,resizable=no,scrollbars,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top;
myWindow = window.open(url, "welcome", windowFeatures);

}
```

and i have called this function in code behind as follows

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=openWindow('newWindow.aspx?id=" & Id & "')>  </a>
```

here the id is users ID 
but new window is replaced in same window
where i am doing wrong
please guide me
Thanks

Comment: you should format your code :]

Answer (score 1):

remove var myWindow from above the function and place it inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You create a window called "welcome" when you run the function for the first time. Subsequent calls replace the content, because a window called "welcome" already exists. Your names need to be **unique**.

Also: Validate. Validate. [Validate](http://validator.w3.org/).

Quotes around attribute values are optional sometimes. This isn't one of those times.

Answer (score 0):

In the `window.open` function, the second argument is the window's name. Using the same name twice will load the new URL in the already-opened window. Just change the name in the function call (e.g. include the ID).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make all popup window name different, otherwise last last one will just overwrite the previous one.

```
 function openWindow(url)   
{
var width = 700;
var height = 500;
var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth/2) - (width/2));
var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight/2) - (height/2));
var windowFeatures = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height + " 
,status,resizable=no,scrollbars,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + "screenX=" + left + 
",screenY=" + top;
myWindow = window.open(url, "welcome", windowFeatures);
myWindow = window.open(url, "welcome2", windowFeatures);
myWindow = window.open(url, "welcome3", windowFeatures);// notice all popup window name is different
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you have to add the `target="_blank"` attribute to your link.

Comment: No, you don't. This is JavaScript.